# No Mapping Exists from Object Type System.Widows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell

Tags: c#, sql, button, stored-procedures, datagridview

I'm new to C# coding and this website so bear with me. On the button click I want my stored procedure to execute and populate the datagridview. When I run the application and click the button I keep getting an error saying:

"No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell to a known managed provider native type."

How do I fix this? I've tried converting the parameters to their data types which doesn't seem to work either. I've been stuck on this for a while and am struggling to find anything on the internet about my specific error. Thank you.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlcn1 = new SqlConnection("My Server Connection String");
        sqlcn1.Open();

        //Stored Procedure
        SqlCommand sqlcmddel = new SqlCommand("My_Stored_Procedure", sqlcn1);
        sqlcmddel.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmddel.ExecuteNonQuery();


        sqlcn1 = new SqlConnection("My Server Connection String");
        sqlcn1.Open();



        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) ;

        SqlCommand sqlcmdins = new SqlCommand("My_Stored_Procedure", sqlcn1);

        //Stored Procedure


        sqlcmdins.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@sugnum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[0];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@sugtype", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[1];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@buyerid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[2];


        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@duedate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[3];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@xrelqty", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[4];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@purchasingfactor", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[5];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@relqty", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[6];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@jobnum", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[7];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@assemblyseq", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[8];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@jobseq", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[9];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@warehousecode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[10];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@fob", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[11];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@shipviacode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[12];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@termscode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[13];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@vendornum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[14];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@purpoint", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[15];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@linedesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[16];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@ium", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[17];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@unitprice", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[18];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@docunitprice", SqlDbType.Float).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[19];
        sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@taxable", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[Ournum].Cells[20];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're trying to pass the Cell into the stored procedure. You need to pass in the cells value.

Also, because you've put a ';' at the end of the foreach call, your loop around the rows isn't doing anything. Assuming you're trying to insert all the rows from the datagridview, you'll need something like this...

```
        using (SqlConnection sqlcn1 = new SqlConnection("My Server Connection String"))
        {
            sqlcn1.Open();

            //Stored Procedure
            using (SqlCommand sqlcmddel = new SqlCommand("My_Stored_Procedure", sqlcn1))
            {
                sqlcmddel.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcmddel.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlcmdins = new SqlCommand("My_Stored_Procedure", sqlcn1))
                {
                    sqlcmdins.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        //Stored Procedure
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@sugnum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[0].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@sugtype", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[1].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@buyerid", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[2].Value;


                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@duedate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = row.Cells[3].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@xrelqty", SqlDbType.Float).Value = row.Cells[4].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@purchasingfactor", SqlDbType.Float).Value = row.Cells[5].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@relqty", SqlDbType.Float).Value = row.Cells[6].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@jobnum", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = row.Cells[7].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@assemblyseq", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = row.Cells[8].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@jobseq", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = row.Cells[9].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@warehousecode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[10].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@fob", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[11].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@shipviacode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[12].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@termscode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[13].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@vendornum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[14].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@purpoint", SqlDbType.Int).Value = row.Cells[15].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@linedesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = row.Cells[16].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@ium", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value = row.Cells[17].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@unitprice", SqlDbType.Float).Value = row.Cells[18].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@docunitprice", SqlDbType.Float).Value = row.Cells[19].Value;
                    sqlcmdins.Parameters.Add("@taxable", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = row.Cells[20].Value;

                    sqlcmdins.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked - getting hung up on a funky error now. "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM" Wondering if you know anything about that?

Comment: Glad that worked. As for the date issue. Due Date is the only date you have. What's the value of the due date you're trying to insert? Quite often this happens because the default value for a DateTime is "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" which falls outside the date range that the database supports.

Comment: There are a 1000+ date values that fill that field from my SQL table. In SQL the date format is "2017-07-20 00:00:00.000". When I execute the application and the datagridview populates, the format is "7/20/2017 12:00:00 AM". Could this be why?